# Own heap implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, heap

I have to write my own implementation of heap in C++, which stores objects of type:

```
std::pair<City, int>
```

where City is a structure to store two integers, which represent city coords and string - city name.
I do know how to do this with plain integers, but using pair of values is a little problematic to me.
I've already started to write my heap class, but, as I said, I don't know how to do this with those pairs.
I want the heap to be sorted by the int value of the pair.

Comment: Try to be more specific with your question. What exactly is the problem? Show a function you tried to write and explain what you are having trouble with.

Comment: What mean "sorted"? Heap provide only 2 operations push and pop Min/Max, he nothing sort. If all data avaible on start then heap unnecessary, enought only simple sorting.

Comment: I think you should implement the comparator operator for this class..

Answer (score 5):

If you know how to do it for `int`s, you're almost there. Treat the `pair` objects just as you would treat `int`s when assigning, but for comparison purposes, use `.second` instead of the value directly.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [`std::make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) which will put a sequence of your pairs into a heap order, see this [online example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e0ddce43a4a669dd4170610e0e38540f-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba). To sort by the int value only, use a C++11 lambda expression that will compare the second element of each pair

**Alternatively**, given that you cannot use any STL heap-related algorithms, but given any self-made implementation of

```
template<typename RandomIt>
void my_make_heap(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
     /* some algorithm using `a < b` to do comparisons */
}
```

you can rewrite it as (or add an overload)

```
template<typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
void my_make_heap(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare, cmp)
{
     /* SAME algorithm, but now using `cmp(a, b)` to do comparisons */
}
```

and then call it as `my_make_heap(first, last, int_cmp)` where the lambda expression compares pairs like this:

```
    typedef std::pair<City, int> Element;
    auto int_cmp = [](Element const& lhs, Element const& rhs) {
         return lhs.second < rhs.second;
    };
```

Comment: 0: Seeing as the question starts with "I have to write my own implementation of heap" and is most likely a homework assignment, this answer isn't really useful.

Comment: I am not allowed to use any of the STL libraries.

Comment: @user2342783 : but you can use std::pair ?

Comment: @user2342783 OK, then if you already have a heap working for `int`, simply re-use that to accept the `int_cmp` as a template parameter. See updated answer.

Comment: @Angew fair point, updated. It would be just so much better if they taught to use STL wherever possible.

Comment: @nouney I mean - I can use basic types from STL, but I cannot use any heap-like classes or functions.

Comment: @Angew - does Visual Studio 2010 support lambda functions from C++11? I am forced to use VS2010 compiler (on a site like ideone.com)

Comment: @user2342783 Yes, lambdas are supported by VS 2010.

Comment: @rhalbersma Well, do this consistently for a few years, and you will have a generation of programmers who don't know *how* to implement a heap. I am all for using the [standard library](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/) as much as possible in production, but schools should still teach the algorithms inside. A programmer needs to understand data structures, if nothing else then to be able to create their own.

Comment: @rhalbersma I sure couldn't code it off the top of my head, but I still learned the principles and algorithms at university. And I've seen people in our department code a fair share of K-d trees and other space-partitioning structures. Teaching to code these things is not to replace the libraries, but to teach programmers to think algorithmically and reason about data structures.

Comment: @Angew I agree completely with you. It's just that in universities too much emphasis is on doing it yourself rather than on understanding invariants + complexity guarantees of data structures and algorithms. If all students properly knew those of the entire STL, I'm sure they would also have enough understanding to combine those basic building blocks into data structures / algorithms of their own. It simply raises the level of abstraction so that they can get to the interesting stuff a lot quicker (and with a lot less bugs)

Answer (score 1):

So from what i understand :

Your structure is something like this ,

```
struct node
{
   int X_coord;
   int y_coord;
   string name;
}
```

And you need to form the Heap based on "int' value of pair ,call it 'x' .

So your pair is

```
pair<node n , int x> ;
```

[This](http://www.cs.uah.edu/~rcoleman/Common/CodeVault/Code/Code211_Heap.html) , is a very readable code for Heap , implemented in a class.

It can be easily modified to your requirement for pair<> value .
Just use , "heap.second" as your key value .